# how to parse json object in php

Tags: php, json

**json code -**

```
"days": [
        {
            "day-code": "SUN", 
            "runs": "Y"
        }, 
        {
            "day-code": "MON", 
            "runs": "Y"
        }, 
        {
            "day-code": "TUE", 
            "runs": "Y"
        }, 
        {
            "day-code": "WED", 
            "runs": "Y"
        }, 
        {
            "day-code": "THU", 
            "runs": "Y"
        }, 
        {
            "day-code": "FRI", 
            "runs": "Y"
        }, 
        {
            "day-code": "SAT", 
            "runs": "Y"
        }
    ]
```

for retrieving the "day-code" from `PHP` by using the following code -

```
days[0]['day-code'];
```

OR

```
days[0][0];
```

php error -

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as
>   array

Can anyone help me from this problem.

Comment: try `json_decode()`

Comment: Please refer https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp

Comment: I already parsed it after that i used for retriving object. I used also (days[0]->day-code) but niether this works. I think problem is in (-) which between day-code.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29308898/218196)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.`json_decode()` with parameter `true` needed.

2.Then you can do like `$json_array['days'][0]['day-code'];`

Working example:- https://eval.in/776344

you can apply `foreach()` also(in the working example to print all values one-by-one)

***Note:-***

The json data you shown is invalid ([check here](http://jsonlint.com/)). It missed starting `{` and closing `}`

Reference:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Eh, why did you reopen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/29308898/218196 is the canonical reference for these kind of questions.

Comment: It really helps me. Thanks alot :)

Comment: @user7865403  glad to help you. welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://php.net/json_decode), you need to specify if you want an associative array instead of an object from json_decode, this would be the code

```
json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

Comment: It would rather be just a comment

Answer (score 0):

First You need to understand Array and stdClass Object to check this you can use `var_dump($var)`

your data contain all numeric index. you can can access it by 0,1,2

and single element of array is an object so you can access it by arrow (->)

So it will be like

```
$days[0]->day-code;
```